# SQL Server SysTable with tstamp of last inserted row of each table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dmv

Is there any system table or dmv in `SQL Server 2008 R2` that contains information regarding the last DML statement (except select) that was issued against any user table?

I see that in sys.tables there is a modify_date column but that's just for any table alteration (DDL statements).
I wouldn't want to create triggers on every table in the db nor a trigger on the database level for this scope.

The reason for this is that I would like to see when was the last time an insert, update or delete statement was made into each table in order to see if I can drop some of the tables that are no longer used - this is for a DWH db, where each table in the db is supposed to have any of these 3 operations at least once a week/month/quarter/year.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:
Enabling Change Data Capture for your DB.
Refer the below link for CDC:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627369%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Option 2:
Create trigger for each table and do logging in common table whenever INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE happens in any table(Old traditional method).

Comment: Thank you for the options but bottom line is there aren't any "shipped" systables or dmvs that holds this kind of information. Unfortunately, neither of the options you provided are feasible in my case, but thanks anyway!